# Probability Risk Evaluation

Tags: probability, risk-assessment

I have a batch of 50 items.
There is an inspection pass/fail criteria and 3 out of 50 failed inspection.

How do I determine if I pick 10 random items from this batch of 50 the probability %age that I will pick at least 1 failed item?

So far I have:
3/50 = 6% bad items
when  I pick 10, I have 10 * 6% chance of picking a bad item = 60% chance I have at least 1 bad item in my picked 10.

But if I had more than 5/50 failed items, it goes beyond 100% chance of picking a bad item...this feels wrong. I feel like only when I get to 50/50 failed items should I get to a 100% chance of having at least 1 failed item in my selection of 10.

Comment: First off, you have to decide whether you're selecting with or without replacement. Either way, I think I'd use a combinatoric argument: count the number of ways you can choose $10$ of the $50$ items, then count how many contain at least one of the $3$ failed items. (it may be easier here to count the complement - how many ways we can pick without picking any of the failed items)

Comment: OP: Your intuition about the flawed logic is partly right, but you don't need to pick all $50$ items to get a $100$ percent chance of having a failed item; you only need to pick $50$ minus one less than the number of failed items.

Comment: So if I say: pick 1 = 3/50 chance; pick 2 = 3/49, pick 3 = 3/48 ... pick 10 = 3/40. The chances of picking a bad item increase the more I pick. But does that mean I have a 3/40 chance that I have picked at least 1 bad item? Again, if the number a failed items exceeds a certain number, final pick 10 is over 100%.